# Baking IK into FCurves

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, baking, inverse-kinematics

I have an object containing multiple models with several IK.  One model has fcurves (euler rotation only) which gives motor to linked IK models.  What I need is bake/convert all IK animations into FCurves.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Bake Action (make sure you're in Pose Mode, it works in Object mode also) and ensure 'apply constraints' is checked. This will clear all your constraint, so if needed I would duplicate the armature and move to another layer before doing this if you need to bake more animations later on.

Answer (score 3):

I made a Blender Addon that automatically creates a new FK mesh/rig without any of the IK/control bones. You can then export that new FK rig wherever you please, while your original remains intact.

I made it because I was having trouble with Bake Action generating a bunch of extra keyframes that I did not want.

You can find it on GitHub - https://github.com/chinedufn/blender-iks-to-fks

Hope it helps!